# Generate dynamic http requests based on the response using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to parse below response and Create dynamic http requests
For example. Response is

```
[
    { UserID:2, UserName:Kumar},
    { UserID:5, UserName:Sunil},
]
```

Need to extract userID values (2,5) from above response and generate below dynamic http requests
https://perftest.com/?userId=2
https://perftest.com/?userId=5

Appreciate if any one can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) as a child of the request which returns the above value and configure it like:

   [image]

   Textual representation of the Regular Expression just in case:

   ```
   UserID\s*:\s*(\d+)
   ```

   where:

   - `s*` - any number of possible whitespace characters
   - `d+` - any number of digits
   - `\` - escape of the [meta-character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
   - `()` - grouping
2. Add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after the request and configure it like:

   [image]
3. Inside ForEach Controller you can reference `2` or `5` as `${UserID}` where required:

   [image]